# Angular 4 Linkedin Follow Button Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, angular, linkedin-api

I'm trying to figure out how I can use these scripts in order to display a linkedin follow button. I am using Angular 4, however, and understand that scripts shouldn't really be used. I am trying to implement the code given by the linkedin developer site

```
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script> 
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="218698" data-counter="right"></script>
```

But it doesn't display. I've tried to see if there are any other alternatives, but the best I found was ng-share, but to my understanding, that doesn't have a follow button, only a share button. I am open to alternatives, but preferably would like to have the button look the same as the one provided by the linkedin developer site.

Edit: I am using an instance in which the twitter widget script is being inserted.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationService } from '../../services/navigation.service';
import { ContentService } from '../../services/content.service';
import { Category } from '../../services/models/category';

import { ShareButtonsModel } from '../../services/models/body-component';
import { BrowserModule, DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'share-buttons',
  templateUrl: './share-buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./share-buttons.component.css']
})
export class ShareButtonsComponent {

    @Input('share-buttons-layout') shareButtonsLayout: ShareButtonsModel;
    @Input('share-buttons-data') shareButtonsData;
    externalHTML: SafeHtml;
    categories: Category[];

    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public cService: ContentService, public nService: NavigationService) {
        let htmlStr = `<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
`;
        this.downloadJS(htmlStr);
        this.externalHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlStr);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.cService.getLayout().subscribe(res => this.categories = res);
    }


    downloadJS(string) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var scripts = parser.parseFromString(string, 'text/html').getElementsByTagName('script');
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        //var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            var src = scripts[i].getAttribute('src');
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            if (src && src.length) {
                script.src = (src);
            } else {
                script.innerHTML = scripts[i].innerHTML;
            }
            document.head.appendChild(script);
            head.removeChild(script);
        }

    }
}
```

And the html where I add the twitter button is here:

```
<!--Twitter Follow-->
    <div *ngIf="button.button==='twitterFollow'">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/dummyComp" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @dummyComp</a>
    </div>
```

It seems to work perfectly fine when I navigate to and from my site.

Comment: Are these in your `index.html` file? That's the only place to include scripts.

Comment: No, these aren't in the index.html file, but from the research I did, these scripts are to be placed in the area where you want the button to display.

Comment: Sadly, you can't include scripts like this directly in your component's html templates, and don't know any workarounds specific to this off the top of my head

Comment: I am using an instance in which the twitter script is being inserted via typescript, but the html element is an a tag not a script.. I will edit my post to clarify.

Comment: I see. I'd first try adding the scripts to the index.html file. Since angular builds a single page web-app they scripts will be in the same area and available. As long as the button html is generated in the DOM separately (as you've shown) this solution should work. If that doesn't work, and you're using angular cli you can add the script to your **angular-cli.json** file.

Comment: The issue being with that is that the linkedin button is created by the scripts. There is no tag that is created separately. Therefore, I cannot put it in the head and just create a button/a tag. Sadly, I've tried looking all over stackoverflow, google, github and nothing is showing up for a follow button in angular 4. ;(

Answer (score 2):

(Angular 5) I am able to display a functional "LinkedIn Follow" button in a component, however it appears that the iframe is corrupted/trashed when navigation is routed to another component and back again.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <div id="linkedin-scripts" style="display:none;">  
      <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">lang: en_US</script>
      <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="" data-counter="right"></script>
    </div>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

your.component.html

```
<div id="linkedin"></div>
```

your.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {
    document.getElementById("linkedin").innerHTML = document.getElementById("linkedin-scripts").innerHTML;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add code in ngAfterViewInit function and add a script tag dynamically such as :-

```
    const s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'in/Login';
    var elementRef = document.getElementById("linkedinBtn"); // element or div 
    where you want to add the button
    elementRef.appendChild(s);
```